# Вывести текст внутри скобок

Tags: c++, текст, вывод, подстрока

Вводится текст с клавиатуры, в тексте открываются скобки, внутри которых содержится другой текст. Нужно вывести этот другой текст через `cout`. Текст может быть в скобках не весь, но вывести нужно только то, что в скобках. Какие функции помогут с этим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простейшим решением будет найти первую (открывающую) и последнюю (закрывающую) скобки в тексте и вывести все символы между ними:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    /* Создаем переменную типа std::string, в которой будет храниться весь
       наш введенный текст: */
    std::string text;

    /* Считываем строку из стандартного потока ввода (из консоли) в нашу
       переменную text: */
    std::getline(std::cin, text);

    /* Находим индексы первой и последней скобки в строке (предполагается,
       что в строке точно есть обе скобки): */
    const auto firstBracketIndex = text.find('(');
    const auto lastBracketIndex = text.rfind(')');

    /* Выводим все символы строки, внутри этих двух скобок: */
    for (size_t i = firstBracketIndex + 1; i < lastBracketIndex; i++)
        std::cout << text[i];
}
```

Пример работы:

```
$ .\program.exe
first (second) third
second
```